# How to handle session which is generated in the setup and teardown methods in pytest in another file test_1.py

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

```py
def setup_method(usern,pwd):
    global token,session
    inputdata=''
    session = requests.Session()
    inputdata={
                "username":"XXXXXt",
                "password":"<XXXxx"
              }
    response = session.post(config.login_url,data=inputdata,headers=config.api_headers)
    token = json.loads(response.text).get('token')
    config.api_headers["X-CSRF-Token"]=json.loads(response.text).get('token')

def teardown_method():
    inputdata=''
    config.api_headers["X-CSRF-Token"]=token
    session.post(config.logout_url,data=inputdata,headers=config.api_headers)    
    #print("logout:",token)
    #assert (json.loads(response.text)).get('ResponseStatus') in "SUCCESS"
```

How to handle session which is generated in the setup and teardown methods in pytest in another file `test_1.py`?

Comment: The above code is in the setup_teardown.py file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use conftest.py for the same - please refer to this documentation available at https://docs.pytest.org/en/2.7.3/plugins.html?highlight=re

Comment: Not the direct solution but helped solve the issue.
I was able to figure out using conftest.py and fixtures.